# mongoose search using regex on findbyid

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to find a user by his mongodb collection's `_id` ,

in need the search to be done using the first 5 characters in the user id

example with `5e9cca` i can find the collection id `5e9cca24beabb96a4caedc35`

```
    var id = req.body.id

    User.findById({ _id : { $regex: '^id', $options: 'i' } },  
     (err, user)  => {
        if (err) {
             console.log(err);
           res.status(400)
       }
```

with this code i got this error :

```
MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: { '$regex': '^id', '$options': 'i' } }" at path "_id" for model "User"
```

PS : The search using the hole id is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoose's [.findById()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) will take in a string & internally it will convert string into `ObjectId()`. So `.findById()` is kind of a wrapper to MongoDB's native function `.findOne()` and all it can take is a string. Additionally you can not do regex search on `_id` field as it's not of type `string`. If at all you need to do this, try below :

**On MongoDB version >4.0 :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Create a field of type 'string' from `_id`*/
  { $addFields: { convertedId: { $toString: "$_id" } } },
  /** Regex search against it */
  {
    $match: {
      convertedId: {
        $regex: "^1a934e",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  },
  /** Remove additionally added field */
  { $project: { convertedId: 0 } }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3P9_ae5N2Sm)